# Determine the form of the sequence {9,144,3600,129600,6350400,...}

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, recreational-mathematics

I'm having a difficult time figuring out the functional form of this sequence:

$$\{9,144,3600,129600,6350400,...\}$$

I'm trying to determine the recursive relationship for a differential equation using power series solutions.

Any help or recommendations are appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like [OEIS sequence A162993](https://oeis.org/A162993)

Answer (score 1):

$$a(n)=\left(\frac{(n+2)!}{2}\right)^2$$
or
$$a_{n+1}=a_n(n+3)^2$$

Comment: Oh geez, that makes my comment above seem stupid, ha! Thanks!

Comment: I've been thinking about group theory recently, so I'd frame it as $|A_{n+2}|^2$, but it's the same answer as above.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\Big\{9\quad\Big|\quad9\times 16\quad\Big|\quad9\times 16\times 25\quad\Big|\quad 9\times 16\times 25\times 36\quad\Big|\quad 9\times 16\times 25\times 36\times 49\quad\Big|\quad \text{and so on ...}\Big\}$$
therefore$$a_1=9\\a_n={\Big[(n+2)!\Big]^2\over 4}$$

Comment: I'd argue that specifying $a_1 = 9$ is superfluous here.

Comment: Yes that's right. I was just calculating a recurrence relation in my mind that time :)

Comment: @Peiffap Well, yes and no, if we consider $a_0=9$ then the formula becomes $(n+3)!^2/4$. Since OP didn't fix the origin index, it somehow has to be explicited.

Comment: @zwim. That's true as well.

Comment: That's a good point! My apologies. The sequence begins at $n=0$